# Sort multiple arrays at once by using their index numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am making a small quiz program that reads single lines of answers from a txt file and puts them into separate arrays, with one of them being the name.

I am attempting to sort multiple arrays at once by using their index number. I am able to sort the names, but the answers themselves do not sort, for example:

Ben:

A

C

Aidan:

B

F

and I will be able to change the order of their names, but can not figure out how to bring their answers with them. Any advice?

This is the code I have so far:

```
String[] names = new String[4];
String[] answersA = new String[7];
String[] answersB = new String[7];
String[] answersC = new String[7];
String[] answersD = new String[7];
String[] answersE = new String[7];
String[] answersF = new String[7];

try {
    Arrays.sort(names);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println("meh");
}
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(names[i]);
    System.out.println(answersA[i]);
    System.out.println(answersB[i]);
    System.out.println(answersC[i]);
    System.out.println(answersD[i]);
    System.out.println(answersE[i]);
    System.out.println(answersF[i]);
}
```

Comment: Learn about classes and objects. You don't want 7 arrays. You want a single array of Player objects, where each Player object would have a name, and 6 answers. Then you can sort the players by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have data that is logically grouped together within your program, and where the cohesive unit has semantic value, that represents an ["object"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) within your program. Objects can contain various types of data, including even other objects.

For this scenario, you've described a student (with a name) and their responses to various quiz questions. The OOP approach here would be to model a Student class that encapsulates these data points, rather than trying to manipulate them independently of each other. A useful exercise is to consider all of the problems your program will be solving, and to think about what types of things make up that problem. You could have a `Student` class, and an `Answer` class for solving your current problem. Your student has a name (which is just plain text), and a series of answers (you can use an array, though the [Java List API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is generally easier to work with). You could also have a `Question` class, if you want to keep track of the problem-statement and its correct answer.

If you still need the ability to sort students, for example, based on their performance on the quiz, you can use a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). It shouldn't be too hard to find examples of how to use that. You could also have your `Student` class implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, in order to sort students by name. That'll allow you to use the `Collections.sort` method to sort your student collection pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Array List the below example will be useful:

```
List<Integer> ids = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3);
List<String> colors = Arrays.asList("blue", "yellow", "red", "black");
List<String> clothes = Arrays.asList("shoes", "pants", "boots", "coat");
```

// Sort By ID

```
concurrentSort(ids, ids, colors, clothes);
```

// Sort By Color

```
concurrentSort(colors, ids, colors, clothes);
```

// Sort By Clothes

```
concurrentSort(clothes, ids, colors, clothes);
```

Concurrent Sort Function is at:

https://ideone.com/cXdw6T

Similar to this you can sort Answer lists based on Names.